# Display image in Android's ImageViewer widget using byte array created on .NET

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, android-imageview, writeablebitmap, bitmapfactory

I have a bunch of images stored in my server's database as byte arrays that I'd like to consume in my Android app.

The byte arrays were created from images in a Windows Phone 7 app, so using .NET's WriteableBitmap (wbmp) to save to an IsolatedStorageFileStream (isfs):

```
     wbmp.SaveJpeg(isfs, newWidth, newHeight, 0, 90);
```

In the Android app, I have an ImageView widget that I'm trying to use to display one of the images.  I've tried using BitmapFactory to decode the byte array (payload):

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(payload, 0, payload.length);
    img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But that doesn't work - no image displays and bmp is null when I step through the debugger.  This seems to indicate that BitmapFactory could not properly decode the byte array.

For Windows Phone 7, I just load the byte[] (reality) into a MemoryStream (mstream), then call the Bitmap (bmp)'s SetSource method with that MemoryStream:

```
    mstream = new MemoryStream(reality);
    bmp.SetSource(mstream);
```

So then on Android I tried reading the byte array into a MemoryFile then loading the MemoryFile's InputStream using BitmapFactory:

```
    MemoryFile mf;
        try {
            mf = new MemoryFile("myFile", payload.length);
            mf.writeBytes(payload, 0, 0, payload.length);
            InputStream is = mf.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            img1.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
        } catch (IOException e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But this still doesn't work.

**How can I successfully load a byte array in this format in Android to display the image?**

Comment: Have you checked logcat to see if there's any errors?

Comment: Yep, it says this:
07-27 01:13:55.629: DEBUG/skia(7808): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Bing and here, this error probably indicates an invalid image.  I would carefully double-check that you are downloading the right URL.  If so, then try printing the contents of that byte[] to the log (or check it in the debugger); see if it's an html message of some sort.

Bingo!  Based on your extra information, this is Base64-encoded data.  What you posted looked too much like plain text, so I tried running it through both uudecode and base64 -d on my Linux machine.  The latter worked, generating a file that was recognized as JPEG.

Decoding this should be quite simple.  Change this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(payload, 0, payload.length);
img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

to this:

```
import android.util.Base64;
...
payload = Base64.decode(payload, Base64.Default);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(payload, 0, payload.length);
img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Let me know!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  It looks like I'm calling the correct web service URL as I'm getting another property of the complex datatype correctly.  It's just the byte[] that isn't decoding using the BitmapFactory class.  Here's the first few characters of the string representation of the byte array: 
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAgwCDAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT

It seems like it is the image data (and this same web service method returns a working byte array that is properly decoded on WP7).

Comment: Just followed up in a .NET project that makes the same call to the web service.  The first part of the string representation of the byte array looks the same.  This leads me to believe that Android's BitmapFactory just doesn't know how to decode it even though it's a valid encoding in .NET.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ckbhodge: I believe I see the issue.  See edited answer above.

Comment: Thanks so much, decoding the byte array using Base64 did the trick!  Thank you!